# nock not setting the authorization header in react

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, mocking, nock

Trying to mock the headers of authorization bearer token and few other headers in nock but nock is erroring out `Nock: No match for request`.

It works without the headers and reqheaders though...

Axios call

```
const details = await axios
    .get(serviceUrl, {
        params,
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer <token>`
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.statusText !== 'OK') {
            throw new Error('Error');
        }
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

Nock mocking

```
nock(baseUrl, {
        reqheaders: {
            authorization: `Bearer <token>`
        }
    })
        .defaultReplyHeaders({
            'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
            'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
        })
        .get('/v1/service')
        .query(query)
        .reply(200, details)
```

Comment: Do you need to include the query params?

Comment: @Phil, added them in ` .query(query)`
All works fine when I comment the header part in axios & nock. But with headers it fails :/

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you verified the token values are exactly the same?

Comment: yes, I they are same. I'll update the code above as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to intercept the pre-flight (cores) request with the response headers to make this work.

Reference: https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/1534

```
nock(baseUrl)
.persist()
.intercept(
    `${baseUrl}?q1=query1&q2=query2`,
    'OPTIONS'
)
.reply(200)
.defaultReplyHeaders({
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-allow-headers': ['Authorization', 'x-otherHeaders']
})
.get('/v1')
.query({ q1: 'query1', q2: 'query2' })
.reply(200, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

`index.test.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import nock from 'nock';

axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http')

describe('74738889', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const query = { id: 1 };
    const details = { id: 1, name: 'teresa teng' };
    const scope = nock('http://localhost', {
      reqheaders: {
        authorization: `Bearer <token>`
      }
    })
      .defaultReplyHeaders({
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
      })
      .get('/v1/service')
      .query(query)
      .reply(200, details)


    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost/v1/service', {
      params: query,
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer <token>`
      }
    });
    console.log('res.data: ', res.data);
    console.log('res.headers', res.headers)
    expect(res.data).toEqual(details);

    scope.done()
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74738889/index.test.ts (10.169 s)
  74738889
    ✓ should pass (30 ms)

  console.log
    res.data:  { id: 1, name: 'teresa teng' }

      at stackoverflow/74738889/index.test.ts:30:13

  console.log
    res.headers {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
    }

      at stackoverflow/74738889/index.test.ts:31:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.668 s, estimated 11 s
```

package versions:

```json
"nock": "^13.2.9",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
```